# Is declaring a variable inside of calling a method bad practice?

Tags: php

If I was to call a method which took a parameter, and then defined a variable at the same time, would that be considered "bad practice"?

Example:

```
if( file_exists( $file = "skins/Default/Controllers/Demo.php" ) )
{
    require( $file );
}
```

I feel as though it makes things easier as it doesn't require creating another variable above, nor does it clutter the code up by writing the string twice.

Comment: When in doubt, always ask yourself "what do I gain if I write code like this". In your case, you gain nothing from performance POV, but you reduce readability. Gains = 0. Loss = 1. I agree with zzzzBov's answer, it covers the topic well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is declaring a variable inside of calling a method bad practice?

Yes, because it hides the intent behind other functionality.

```
$file = "skins/Default/Controllers/Demo.php";
if (file_exists($file)) {
    require($file);
}
```

is easier to read and reason about than:

```
if (file_exists($file = "skins/Default/Controllers/Demo.php")) {
    require($file);
}
```

because it'd be easily mistaken for `$file == "skins/Default/Controllers/Demo.php"`, which is common to see within an `if` statement.

Comment: Thank you, you gave an example of how the code should be and why it's bad practice to write it as I had thought. Interesting as I hadn't thought about how it could have gotten mistaken for ==

Answer (score 0):

it could be considered as bad practice, as it reduces readability (=> maintainability) of the code.

```
$file = "skins/Default/Controllers/Demo.php";
if( file_exists( $file ) )
{
    require( $file );
}
```

is more readable

Comment: Thank you, I felt as though zzzzBov's answer had a little more detail as to why it is considered bad practice.